# How to pass class instance scope to callback function?

Tags: php, methods, scope, callback, this

I'm in the process of rewriting an MVC framework I've written. I've decided to incorporate explicit routing in addition to my framework's default routing behavior, but I'm having an issue.

This is the method that executed a route (It's a method on the `App` class)...

```
private function executeRoute($requestType, $route, $callback)
    {
      if (is_array($requestType))
      {
        if (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $requestType))
          $matched = true;
        else
          $matched = false;
      }
      else if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == $requestType) || ($requestType == "ALL"))
        $matched = true;
      else
        $matched = false;
      if ($matched)
      {
        $uriVariables = $this->getUriVariables($route, implode("/", $this->uri));
        if (is_array($uriVariables))
          call_user_func_array($callback, $uriVariables);
      }
    }
```

Here's where I'm having trouble...

```
$app = new App;

  $app->all("/", function() {
    $controller = $app->setController("test");
    if ($controller)
    {
      $app->controller->index();
    }
    else
      echo $controller;
  });
```

This isn't working because the callback function has it's own scope that doesn't contain the instance of my `App` class. Is there a way to pass a reference to the callback function without the developer explicitly adding his `App` instance as a dependency/argument to the callback function?

I would like to be able to use `$app` inside of the callback, or rewrite `$this` to a reference to the `App` instance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [use](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-200) to inherit variables from the parent scope.

```
$app = new App;

$app->all("/", function() use ($app) {
    $controller = $app->setController("test");
    if ($controller)
    {
        $app->controller->index();
    }
    else
        echo $controller;
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that implicitly without passing that to the function? Thanks for the answer, by the way.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the only way to access parent scope in PHP.